# R - non linear regression (nls) and polynomial interactions (poly)

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, nls

I can run a `nls` regression at R if I explicitly define the parameters ("a" and "b" in the example below). However, how could I code the `nls` with a generic number of variables/higher degress in the `poly` function?

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100), var2 = rnorm(100))

p <- as.data.frame(poly(df$var2, degree = 2))

names(p) <- paste0("poly", names(p))

df <- cbind(df, p)

nls(var1 ~ a*poly1 + b*poly2, data = df, start = list(a = 1, b = 2))
```

Trying code, as is done with the `lm` function, is not possible:

```
nls(var1 ~ poly(var2, degree = 2), data = df, start = list(a = 1, b = 2)) #=> Error
```

Comment: This is basically the same question asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643606/r-polynomial-shortcut-notation-in-nls-formula (which doesn't have a direct answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly multiply the polynomial terms and the coefficients you're estimating (`a` and `b`), as you did in the first example. You can do this with matrix multiplication.

Note that `poly` returns a matrix, where the rows line up with your data and the columns are the polynomial terms:

```
> dim(poly(df$var2, degree = 2))
[1] 100   2
```

Therefore, rather than working with `a` and `b` separately, combine them into a vector and multiply the 100 x 2 matrix with this 2 x 1 vector:

```
nls(var1 ~ poly(var2, degree = 2) %*% coef, data = df,
    start = list(coef = c(a = 1, b = 2)))
```

This gives the same answer as your working example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100), var2 = rnorm(100))

getPoly <- function(df, degree=2) {
    p <- poly(df$var2, degree = degree)
    colnames(p) <- paste0("poly", colnames(p))
    new_df <- cbind(df, p)
    formula_str <- paste0("var1~",paste0(paste0(letters[1:degree], "*poly", 1:degree), collapse="+"))
    return(list(df=new_df, formula_str=formula_str))
}

poly_data <- getPoly(df, 3)
start_list <- list(a=1,b=2, c=3)

nls(as.formula(poly_data$formula_str), data = poly_data$df, start = start_list)
```