# How to include parameter "a" in a poly approach in nls?

Tags: r, nls, poly

I want to use `poly` in a an exponential `nls` function. Consider following two models.

```
## model 1
nls(y ~ exp(a + b*x), data=dat, start=list(a=0, b=0))
#           a           b  ## coefs
# -4.13220156  0.05972285 

## model 2
nls(y ~ exp(a + b*x + c*I(x^2)), data=dat, start=list(a=0, b=0, c=0))
#          a          b          c 
# -3.0603943  0.0300680  0.0001941
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039038/6574038), I was able to solve this without parameter `a`.

```
nls(y ~ exp(b*x), data=dat, start=list(b=0))
#       b 
# 0.01071 
nls(y ~ exp(poly(x, 1, raw=T) %*% coef), data=dat, start=list(coef=0))
#    coef 
# 0.01071 

nls(y ~ exp(b*x + c*I(x^2)), data=dat, start=list(b=0, c=0))
#          b          c 
# -0.0562947  0.0007633 
nls(y ~ exp(poly(x, 2, raw=T) %*% coef), data=dat, start=list(coef=rep(0, 2)))
#      coef1      coef2 
# -0.0562947  0.0007633
```

However, I couldn't find a way to include parameter `a` to reproduce *model 1* and *model 2* from above with `poly`.

*My failed attempts so far*

```
nls(y ~ exp(c(a, poly(x, 2, raw=T)) %*% coef), data=dat, 
    start=list(coef=setNames(rep(0, 3), letters[1:3])))
nls(y ~ exp(cbind(a, poly(x, 2, raw=T)) %*% coef), data=dat, 
    start=setNames(replicate(3, list(0)), letters[1:3]))
nls(y ~ exp(cbind(as.matrix(a), poly(x, 2, raw=T)) %*% coef), data=dat, 
    start=list(coef=setNames(replicate(3, list(0)), letters[1:3])))
nls(y ~ a*exp(poly(x, 2, raw=T) %*% coef), data=dat, 
    start=list(coef=setNames(replicate(3, list(0)), letters[1:3])))
nls(y ~ exp(a*lapply(coef, `[`, 1) + poly(x, 2, raw=T) %*% lapply(coef, `[`, -1)), 
    data=dat, start=list(coef=setNames(rep(0, 3), letters[1:3])))
nls(y ~ a*lapply(coef, `[`, 1)*exp(poly(x, 2, raw=T) %*% lapply(coef, `[`, -1)), 
    data=dat, start=list(coef=setNames(rep(0, 3), letters[1:3])))
```

*yield similar error messages:*

```
Error in nls(y ~ exp(c(a, poly(x, 2, raw = T)) %*% coef), data = dat,  : 
  parameters without starting value in 'data': a
```

**How may I include parameter `a` in a `poly` approach?**

---

*Data*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(y=sort(rexp(100, 1) + rnorm(100)), x=1:100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let coef be the entire coefficient vector including a and cbind 1 to poly:

```
nls(y ~ exp(cbind(1, poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)) %*% coef), data = dat,
  start = list(coef = numeric(3)))
```

or just add `a` to poly:

```
nls(y ~ exp(a + poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE) %*% coef), data = dat,
  start = list(a = 0, coef = numeric(2)))
```